# How do you show multiple locations on a map with .NET MAUI?

Tags: .net-maui

I have been able to open the default map application and display a single location:

```
 var location = new Location(latitude, longitude);
 var options = new MapLaunchOptions { Name = locationName };

 try
 {
     await Map.Default.OpenAsync(location, options);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     // No map application available to open
 }
```

Wondering if the ability to open with multiple locations pinned exists?

Comment: No answers on this yet? Surprised. I'm also currently working on this, and if I find something out will post here.

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to load in the location data, whether that is from an embedded resource or API call. Once you have the lat/lng data pulled in (mine is in a List) you can go ahead and add them. You will need `map.Layers.Add(CreatePointLayer());` to call the code below:

```
    private MemoryLayer CreatePointLayer()
    {
        return new MemoryLayer
        {
            Name = "Points",
            IsMapInfoLayer = true,
            Features = GetLocsFromList(),
            Style = SymbolStyles.CreatePinStyle()
        };
    }

    private IEnumerable<IFeature> GetLocsFromList()
    {
        var locs = Locs; //<- Locs is the List<Locations>

        return locs.Select(l => {
            var feature = new PointFeature(SphericalMercator.FromLonLat(l.lng, l.lat).ToMPoint());
            return feature;
        });
    }
```

Comment: are you using an API? Actually we wanted a solution from integrated Maui Map, and not using an API.

Comment: There was no integrated Maui Map until .NET 7 which did not release until November 8. So yes I was using MAPSUI NuGet package